# Systematic Reed-Muller code

Tags: coding-theory

Reed–Muller codes are a family of linear error-correcting codes used in communications.
The code of $RM(2,3)$ could be generated with matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
In several sources I have read there is a way to build systematic Reed-Muller code which keeps recieved signal of length $n$ in first $n$ bits of output signal. But I couldn't find how to do it.   Any ideas?

Comment: Linear algebra will see you home. Take your generator matrix, and do whatever elementary row operations are needed to bring it to a reduced row echelon form. If it is possible to use the first $k$ bits as the payload carrying bits, what you got will have a $k\times k$ identity block in the left. In the case of this matrix the last column has all ones. This is hardly a surprise given that this RM-code consists of all the even weight words of length 8.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How did you get that code consists of all even-weight words and how this fact helps me?

Comment: The space of even weight words is 7-dimensional. This code is 7-dimensional, and it is a subset of the even weight code. By linear algebra they are the same subspace. For if this code did not include all the even weight words its dimension would be less than 7.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why the code is a subset of the even weight words space?

Comment: The even weight words form a subspace. All the rows of this matrix have an even weight. The rowspace of a matrix (=the code generated) is the smallest subspace containing all its rows. Ergo, the rowspace is contained in the even weight space.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen How to keep error-detecting and error-correcting properties while transforming code generator to matrix having identity block in the left? My idea is to add rows of weight $1$ to generator and inverse it to new matrix $M$. Modified coding algorithm consists of two steps: 1) multiply signal to generator matrix $G$. 2) multiply code to $M$. Modified decoding algorithm consists of 1) multiply code to $M^(-1)$. 2) majority logic deduction. But code of signal would be just signal itself with additional zeros in last bits.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My goal is to solve this problem in general for all $RM(r, n)$. So I can't use the fact that code words is of even weight.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking about $RM(2,3)$ only. The answer to 1) depends on whether you want to use systematic encoding or not. For decoding all I can say is to point you at e.g.[MacWilliams & Sloane](http://www.amazon.com/Theory-Error-Correcting-North-Holland-Mathematical-Library/dp/0444851933). Too long for me to explain it here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I know how to decode non-systematic code. The question is whether it's a good idea to divide coding algorithm to standard part and additional transformation $T$ making code systematic and divide decoding algorithm to inversed transformation $T$ and standard decoding. If it is then as it follows from linear algebra transformation $T$ must be multiplication of code word (non-systematic) and some matrix $M$, which could be found from equation $GM=A$, where $A$ has identity block in the left. Then what matrix $A$ must have in its right columns?

Answer (score 2):

The standard description of a $(r,m)$ Reed-Muller code is that there
are $k = \sum_{i=0}^r \binom{m}{i}$ information bits that are denoted as
\begin{align}
&d_0\\
&d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_m\\
&d_{1,2}, d_{1,3}, \ldots, d_{1,m}, d_{2,3}, d_{2,4}, \ldots, d_{m-1,m}\\
&\ddots\\
&d_{1,2,\ldots, r-1, r}, d_{1,2,\ldots, r-1, r+1}, \ldots
\end{align}
where the $i$-th row above lists $\binom{m}{i}$ bits on it, and the
transmitted codeword is the sequence of values 
$(c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{2^m-1})$ of the 
degree $r$ $m$-variate *polynomial* 
\begin{align}
&d_0\\
\oplus \ &d_1x_1 \oplus d_2x_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus x_md_m\\
\oplus \ &d_{1,2} x_1x_2 \oplus d_{1,3}x_1x_3 \oplus \ldots
\oplus d_{1,m}x_1x_m \oplus d_{2,3}x_2x_3 \oplus d_{2,4}x_2x_4 \oplus \ldots
\oplus d_{m-1,m}x_{m-1}x_m\\
\oplus \ &\ddots\\
\oplus \ &d_{1,2,\ldots, r-1, r}x_1x_2\cdots x_{r-1}x_r
\oplus  d_{1,2,\ldots, r-1, r+1}x_1x_2\cdots x_{r-1}x_{r+1}
\oplus \ldots 
\end{align}
as $(x_m, x_{m-1}, \ldots, x_2, x_1)$ varies from
$(0,0, \ldots, 0)$ to $(1,1,\ldots, 1)$.
So, upon receiving the $2^m$ bits, one can apply the
standard Reed-Muller decoding algorithm to recover
the $d$'s and then *reconstruct* the codeword
$(c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{2^m-1})$. If we want to
think of $(c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{k-1})$ as the
*real* information bits $(D_0, D_1, \ldots, D_{k-1})$, 
then so be it: the decoder's job is done.

The harder question is at the *transmitter:* we want to
find $d_0, d_1, \ldots, $ corresponding to the *real*
information bits so that the standard Reed-Muller encoding
produces for us the codeword
$$(c_0, c_1, \ldots, c_{2^m-1})
= (D_0, D_1, \ldots, D_{k-1}, c_k, \ldots, c_{2^m-1})$$
in which the leading $k$ bits are the information bits.
Not to worry. As @JyrkiLahtonen's comments point out,
linear algebra rides to the rescue. Do row transformations
on the given generator matrix $G$ of the standard
Reed-Muller code to transform it into $\hat{G} = [I\mid P]$.
$G$ and $\hat{G}$ **have the same row space.** So, at the
transmitter, we have that
$$(D_0, D_1, \ldots, D_{k-1})\hat{G}
= (D_0, D_1, \ldots, D_{k-1}, c_k, \ldots, c_{2^m-1})$$
**exactly the same codeword** as we would have gotten if
we had first laboriously transformed $(D_0, D_1, \ldots, D_{k-1})$ into
the $d$'s and then applied the standard Reed-Muller encoding
procedure!

> In summary,
>
> - Use $(D_0, D_1, \ldots, D_{k-1})\hat{G}$ to encode at the transmitter. DO NOT attempt to convert the $D$'s to the $d$'s to be followed by standard Reed-Muller encoding.
> - Decode the received word using standard Reed-Muller decoding. This will give you the $d$'s. *USE standard Reed-Muller* **en**coding
>     to reconstruct the transmitted codeword, and take its first $k$ bits as the information bits.

Comment: What knowledge is required for Coding theory?